# Description of an op amp circuit with a capacitor.

Tags: operational-amplifier, active-filter

[image]

I have this circuit consisting of an op amp, a resistor, a capacitor and a voltage source. Based on my understanding, all I believe this circuit does is act as an active low pass filter because of the way the capacitor and resistor are set up. Is there a better way to explain what this circuit does?

Comment: You can analyze the low-frequency behavior by assuming the capacitor is open circuit. What does that tell you?

Comment: No - it is certainly NOT an active lowpass.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a comparator with some short-term hysteresis.

At DC, the circuit simplifies to this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4HXDUm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Op amp inputs have a very high impedance, so R can be ignored.)

This is just a comparator. If \$V_i > 0\$, the output goes as negative as possible. If \$V_i < 0\$, the output goes as positive as possible.

Adding in the R-C circuit affects the non-inverting input voltage when the output switches.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCcQdym.png)</sup>

When the output switches from negative to positive, it charges up the capacitor through the resistor. This current creates a voltage across the resistor, which boosts the voltage at the non-inverting input. This effectively moves the input threshold, making the circuit more resistance to noise. It won't last very long, but maybe it doesn't have to.

If the circuit is drawn incorrectly and the inverting input was supposed to be on the bottom, then I'd call it a non-inverting integrator. It's definitely not a low-pass filter because there's a capacitor between the output and the feedback terminal. That opens the feedback path at low frequencies, which increases the gain.

Comment: It's a zero-crossing detector with transient hysteresis.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds better.

Comment: Well sure. You can always find fancy words to make things sound better. Although it is a slightly better description since it mentions that the comparator is detecting (approximately) zero volts.